# Jackson fails to ignore private static field with complex object type

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I have a class which contains the following line:

```
private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc = new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(MyClass.class, true);
```

When I try to deserialize a JSON message which corresponds to this class, Jackson's introspector hits TypeDesc and tries to resolve it's contents.

The typeDesc field is NOT included in the JSON message and I have configured Jackson to ignore this field, so this issue seems to be part of Jackson's initialization routine that occurs BEFORE deserialization begins.

Has anyone encountered this before? If so, what's the fix? Any suggested workarounds besides reverse engineering Jackson itself?

---

Here's the trailing end of the stacktrace if it helps:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/discovery/tools/DiscoverSingleton
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
at org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc.<clinit>(TypeDesc.java:61)
at com.mypackage.MyClass.<clinit>(MyClass.java:2747)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedConstructor.call(AnnotatedConstructor.java:120)
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating the field with `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a jackson problem, it is in your classpath. It is a static field thus it will be initialized when the class is loaded. The error says it does not find discoversingleton class, you need the jar containing this class in your classpath. Nothing to do with Jackson

Comment: I'm not sure that it should matter. Look at the last line of the stacktrace. It all started with Jackson's introspector.

Comment: If this was just a java a classpath issue, why would the introspector be in play?

Comment: I know :) good initiative to finally verify it, always try to isolate the problem and reproduce it, this way you will be able to solve most of them